# Laravel resource controller method throws exception when autowiring occurs

Tags: laravel

I have a resource route like this:

`Route::apiResource('channels', ChannelController::class);`

My controller has a method:

```
public function destroy(Channel $channel): Response
   {
       $channel->delete();
       return response()->noContent();
   }
```

When I make api call like this:

```
DELETE: http://localhost/my_api/public/api/channels/5
```

and there is an id=5 in the channels table - code works fine, but if path parameter is some string or id not present in DB, autowiring throws an exception like this:

```
Error: Call to a member function bind() on null in file
```

How could I handle such an error?